# Find Difference of Time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, time

I have data from biometric attendance device and I am tasked to create a report of how late an employee comes in on daily basis.

1. I have Column A in h:mm:ss AM/PM format
2. I have Columns B in h:mm:ss AM/PM format

I need to calculate the time difference in Hours and Minutes separately in column C and D respectively only if the status in time in column A is greater than time in column B

```
|   Column A    |   Column B   |  Column C  |    Column D  |
|  8:23:00 AM   |  9:00:00 AM  |     0      |       0      |
|  9:00:00 AM   |  9:00:00 AM  |     0      |       0      |
| 10:05:00 AM   |  9:00:00 AM  |    01      |       05     |
```

Please help!! i'm stuck doing this for past 3 days :(

Comment: I would take a look at [this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/24/calculate-time-excel/), it might help.

Comment: Your job is E.V.I.L. Leave it now. Else it will consume you.

Answer (score 1):

The images below will hopefully help.  Make sure in the minutes formula you add the x 1440 (minutes in a day) and subtract the 60 minutes times the number of hours in the prior column.

[image]

[image]

Brad

Answer (score 1):

Like many things in Excel, there are many ways to do this.  Here's another.

First, recognize that the format is irrelevant.  Times are stored as decimal fraction of a day.  From that, you can pick a format to display it in any human-readable form your want, or display just a derived time component (as BradR did with the TEXT function to display just the hours, and Excel figured out how to extract hours from the time value).

Since Excel works with all time values as fractions of a day, regardless of how you format it, it is all in the same units internally.  So you can do simple arithmetic with the times.  You don't need to extract human-friendly units like hours or minutes and work with those; that can be done with the result, either by formatting or using time functions.

[image]

To get the time difference only if A1 is greater than B1, you can use:

```
=MAX(0,A1-B1)
```

If the subtraction yields a negative number (because A1 is less than B1), MAX will return `0`.  To display just particular time units, you can use time functions.  HOUR returns the whole hours contained in the time value, MINUTE returns the whole minutes.  Columns C and D just wrap the time difference with the relevant function.

```
C1:  =HOUR(MAX(0,A1-B1))
D1:  =MINUTE(MAX(0,A1-B1))
```